# Mean of structure's line

Tags: matlab, structure, mean

I have a structure like

```
struct =
Fields   Subject1          Subject2        Subject3      Subject4
    1 30000x1 double    30000x1 double  30000x1 double  30000x1 double
    2 30000x1 double    30000x1 double  30000x1 double  30000x1 double
    3 30000x1 double    30000x1 double  30000x1 double  30000x1 double
    4 30000x1 double    30000x1 double  30000x1 double  30000x1 double
```

where 1,2,3 and 4 are conditions

I would like to calculate the mean for each condition, so for each LINE of the struture.

I tried with :

```
for i = 1:length(struct)
mean_condition(i) = mean([strut(i)]);
end
```

but I obtain this error

```
Error using sum
Invalid data type. First argument must be numeric or logical.

Error in mean (line 117)
        y = sum(x, dim, flag)/size(x,dim);
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [`structfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/structfun.html) allows you to perform an operation over the fields of a structure, it only works with scalar arrays. Because you have a structure array, you'll need to use an explicit loop or an implicit [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) loop.

As an example of the latter:

```
condition(1).subject1 = 1:10;
condition(1).subject2 = 1:20;
condition(2).subject1 = 1:30;
condition(2).subject2 = 1:40;

results = arrayfun(@(x)mean(structfun(@mean, x)), condition).';
```

Which gives us:

```
results =

     8
    18
```

Which we can verify with:

```
>> [mean([mean(condition(1).subject1), mean(condition(1).subject2)]); mean([mean(condition(2).subject1), mean(condition(2).subject2)])]

ans =

   8
   18
```

---

Depending on MATLAB version, the `*fun` functions may be slower than the explicit loop due to additional function call overhead. This is certainly the case with older versions of MATLAB, but engine improvements have started to bring parity to their performance.

For completeness sake, an explicit loop version:

```
results = zeros(numel(condition, 1));
for ii = 1:numel(condition)
    tmpnames = fieldnames(condition(ii));
    tmpmeans = zeros(numel(tmpnames, 1));
    for jj = 1:numel(tmpnames)
        tmpmeans(jj) = mean(condition(ii).(tmpnames{jj}));
    end
    results(ii) = mean(tmpmeans);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the fields of all the structs in the array have the same size, you can perform this computation very easily as follows:

```
s = struct();
s_len = 4;

for i = 1:s_len
    s(i).Subject1 = repmat(i,30,1);
    s(i).Subject2 = repmat(i,30,1);
    s(i).Subject3 = repmat(i,30,1);
    s(i).Subject4 = repmat(i,30,1);
end

m = reshape(mean(cell2mat(struct2cell(s))),s_len,1);
```

The variable `m` is then a row vector of double values in which each row contains the mean of the respective condition:

```
m =
     1 % mean of condition 1
     2 % mean of condition 2
     3 % mean of condition 3
     4 % mean of condition 4
```